# Can we cancel or delete Github - pull requests?

Tags: git, file, github, repository

Without verifying code, I committed and given pull request in Github.

**Is it possible to cancel or delete my pull request**, instead of declining by repository admin?

If yes, how to cancel or delete pull request in github?